# Dimensionality Reduction

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I have a very basic doubt, are the number of rows/ observations in the data reduced during feature selection techniques like filter/ wrapper methods or during dimensionality reduction using PCA/ LDA/ SVD. Or is it just reduction in number of columns/ variables?

Please explain in detail.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, number of observations has nothing to do with feature selection or dimensionality reduction methods. You'll only reduce the number of features in your data. Number of observations are typically reduced by procedures like outlier elimination or undersampling.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensionality reduction (we also term it "variable selection", "feature engineering", etc.) is a technique to reduce the number of explanatory variables in a statistical model, e.g., regression. It will reduce the number of column variables, not the number of rows. If there are too many rows and it has heavy computational burden, then we can sample the rows using a smart strategy, such as stratified sampling.